# How do I get data from mongodb with 'authenticationDatabase admin' option using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb

I have to get data from remote mongodb. I can do that using command prompt with the command:

`mongo -u root -p "xxxpass" xxxhost:27017/xxxdb --authenticationDatabase admin`

But, with python, in`mycols.find({},{ "_id": 0})` step, I get Authentication failed.

I used `pymongo.MongoClient` with `host, port, user, password`. But, I have not figured out how I can implement `authenticationDatabase admin` into the code. I have used `authSource="admin"` but did not work.

Even when I skip `--authenticationDatabase admin` command in the command prompt, I get the same error.

```
import pymongo
import pprint
import os
import urllib

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
host = "xxxhost"
port = 27017
dbname = "xxxdb"
authdb = "admin"
user = "root"
password = "xxxpass"
tablenames = ["companies"]
connection = [host, port, dbname, authdb, user, password]


def getdata(connection, tablenamelist):
    myclient = pymongo.MongoClient(host=connection[0], port=connection[1], username=urllib.parse.quote(connection[4]), password=urllib.parse.quote(connection[5]), authSource="admin")
    mydb = myclient[connection[2]]

    for elem in tablenamelist:
        mycols = mydb[elem]

        rows = ""
        with open(dir_path+'/'+elem+'.txt','w') as f:
            for elm in mycols.find({},{ "_id": 0}):
                f.write(str(elm) + "\n")
                rows = rows + str(elm)
        f.close()

        print('tablename:', elem)

getdata(connection, tablenames)
```

How do I implement `authenticationDatabase = "admin"` option?

Thank you all from now

Answer (score 0):

The parameter is authSource (and admin is the default if not provided) so something else is likely up (maybe with the username and password).

I might steer you toward using connection strings; there a bit easier to manage once you're used to them. This snippet might help.

```
connection_string = 'mongodb://{}:{}@{}:{}/{}?authSource={}'.format(username, password, host, port, database, auth_source)
client = pymongo.MongoClient(connection_string)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it works. But I do not understand why authSource="admin" option in my code does not work. Anyway, your advice about the connection string is helpfull, too. Thank you again